# How to find the Horizontal and Vertical asymptotes of $\frac{x}{(x^4+1)^{\frac{1}{4}}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics

> How do I find the horizontal and vertical asymptotes of the following?: $\frac{x}{(x^4+1)^{\frac{1}{4}}}$

Based on the definition of being a horizontal asymptote, I must therefore find out the limit as x approaches positive and negative infinity

But I tried to rationalize the denominator but in vain and I was wondering what would be the best method of carrying out this problem?

BTW

My school textbook stated that I must multiply the fraction with : $\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{1}{(x^4)^{\frac{1}{4}}}}$

But that confused me because the numerator and the denominator are not of the same value and thus wouldn't that be incorrect?

*Please excuse my inadequecy of calculus*

Comment: Are you asking if $(x^4)^\frac{1}{4}$ is $x$?

Comment: So were these answers helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s always good to check for **vertical asymptotes** where the function is not defined (after you factor out removable discontinuities). The function $$\frac{x}{\left( x^4+1 \right)^{1/4}}$$ does not exist when we have a divide-by-zero situation; in other words, where

$$\begin{align}
\left( x^4+1 \right)^{1/4} &= 0 \\
x^4+1 &= 0 \\
x^4 &= -1 \\
\end{align}$$

So it looks like we don’t have any vertical asymptotes on the real line—sweet!

---

**Horizontal asymptotes** are a limit as $x\to\pm\infty$. I’ll teach you a snazzy little acronym that we learned in algebra and used in calculus

> BOBO BOTS EATS DC

For rational functions, if the power

- IS **B**igger **O**n **B**ottom, the horizontal asymptote as $x\to\infty$ is $0$
- is **B**igger **O**n **T**op, the asymptote is a **S**lant asymptote (irrelevant here)
- if the **E**xponents **A**re **T**he **S**ame, you **D**ivide **C**oefficients

EATS DC comes with a caveat: you just look at the leading power of $x$, the degree of the numerator and denominator polynomial jumbo.

So we know that the polynomial would look something like this if we solved the radical:

$$\frac{x}{ \sqrt[4]1 \cdot x^{4/4}+\cdots} = \frac{x}{1x^1+\cdots}$$

and that’s good enough! (Note: always be careful with the coefficients when taking care of that exponent.) Of course, $1/1=$, so we have

$$\text{horizontal asymptote: }y=1$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[ \frac{x}{\left( x^4+1 \right)^{1/4}} \right]=1$$

But there’s a catch!

Because this function is symmetrical about the origin, it also holds that

$$\text{horizontal asymptote: }y=-1$$
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left[ \frac{x}{\left( x^4+1 \right)^{1/4}} \right]=-1$$

This is because the $x$ up top introduces the negative sign as $x\to-\infty$ whereas the $1$-over-even-power exponent makes $\left( x^4+1 \right)^{1/4}$ positive for negative $x$.

---

Looking at a graph (which I assume you aren’t allowed to do) confirms all three of these! (I recommend [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/aw8dn1608p).)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something slightly different from what the textbook suggested.

Start with the observation that
$$
x =
\begin{cases}
(x^4)^{1/4}, & x>0 \\
-(x^4)^{1/4}, & x<0 .
\end{cases}
$$

Now you are ready to multiply both numerator and denominator by $(x^{-4})^{1/4}$, so you obtain
$$
\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} \frac{x}{(x^4+1)^{1/4}}
= \lim_{x\to\pm\infty} \frac{\pm (x^4)^{1/4}}{(x^4+1)^{1/4}}
= \lim_{x\to\pm\infty} \frac{\pm (x^4)^{1/4}(x^{-4})^{1/4}}{(x^4+1)^{1/4}(x^{-4})^{1/4}}
= \lim_{x\to\pm\infty} \frac{\pm 1}{(1+x^{-4})^{1/4}}
= \pm \frac{1}{(1+0)^{1/4}} = \pm 1.
$$

So the horizontal asymptotes are $y=1$ and $y=-1$.

There are no vertical asymptotes because the function is continuous at every $x\in\mathbb{R}$.